# Maven: Extract parts of a text file to variables

Tags: regex, maven

Is there a way with Maven to parse an external text file and to extract variables using regex ? The Use-Case is that i have an external-file which cannot be changed. This file is not a proerties file but a C-Header file.

What I would like to do is that maven extracts portions which are in the header file to a variable, like version and to use this variables during the build.

The process might look like this:

1. Maven reads the header-file
2. Maven extracts the Major version using
   regex on the files contents
3. Maven extracts the Minor version using
   regex on the files contents
4. Maven uses extracted Major and Minor
   version during build.

I did search the net but didnt find a solution to this and currently stuck.

Comment: I'm betting you are going to have to write a special maven plugin for this one.

Comment: @AndrewWhite bet lost ;-)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) to read the header file and to create a properties file from its content.
2. Use the [Properties Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/) to use the properties file.

Comment: How would you use Exec in a way that isn't platform specific?

Comment: @AndrewWhite Good point, but OP didn't mention that it has to be platform-independent. And _"execute [...] Java programs"_ gives you platform-independence.

Comment: @GeriBroser your solution is a solution therefore i upvote it but i found a better way to do it (for me). I will accept also the question which gets the next two upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution which is convenient for me using **groovy maven plugin**.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <defaults>
                    <name>Xenu</name>
                </defaults>
                <source>
                    String fileContents = new File("${project.basedir}/../include/version.h").getText('UTF-8')
                    matcher = (fileContents =~ /(?s).*MAJOR ([0-9]+).*?/)
                    String major_version = matcher.getAt(0).getAt(1)
                    matcher = (fileContents =~ /(?s).*MINOR ([0-9]+).*?/)
                    String minor_version = matcher.getAt(0).getAt(1)
                    matcher = (fileContents =~ /(?s).*PATCH ([0-9]+).*?/)
                    String patch_version = matcher.getAt(0).getAt(1)
                    String version = String.format('%s.%s.%s', major_version, minor_version, patch_version)
                    // Set version to be used in pom.properties
                    project.version = version
                    // Set version to be set as jar name
                    project.build.finalName = project.artifactId + "-" + version
                </source>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```